# Title of a 1 or at most 2 page short SF-story about aliens coming to our solar system and bringing the cure

Tags: story-identification

The story is basically a very positive tale of aliens on the way to our solar system to meet us and promising the solution to some big problems of us humans like the cure for cancer, cheap, clean energy etc..
The twist at the very end is they also are very happy to be able to offer the cure for
 the caucasians amongst us.
Made me laugh and think at the time and would love to be able to put a title/ Author to this, so i could properly attribute it and share it in it's original.

If anyone knows this, many thanks in advance!

Editted right after posting : 
Wow great site people, found it already in an already answered linked post!
I was thinking of Reunion by Arthur C. Clarke : 
We have a simple remedy for the offensive yet harmless genetic plague that afflicted so many of the colonists. […]  People of Earth, you can rejoin the society of the universe without shame, without embarrassment.

If any of you are still white, we can cure you.

:)